# Magento on Local Host won't show any image or CSS files?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, localhost

I am running a copy of Magento on my localhost so that I can make changes without affecting the live site. I have imported a database which was backed up from the 'live' site and have changed the web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url to http://localhost/magento/ and I am able to see my database BUT I can't see any of the skins, image files etc. I know this is linked to the database because if I change the DB credentials in local.xml to a different database it loads everything perfectly. Problem though is that I need this database.

Any ideas?

I have also tried 'http://localhost:8888/magento/index.php/' to be more precise and see if that works, but it didn't. I've spent hours trying to get this up and running and am so close!

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER: I had to update the media_url and skin_url in the back database with http://localhost:8888/magento/skin etc

Comment: please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the trailing slash. The base_urls must set to http://localhost/magento/

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote it down wrong. I do have this on the database side.

Comment: Did you check in the table `core_config_data` the urls like  `media_urls`or `skin_urls`?

Comment: Good point! Would I also change these to: http://localhost/magento/   or http://localhost/magento/skin/  or..?

Comment: (it removed the forward slashes, but I know I would need these at the end). Tried both of those for 'skin' but couldn't get them working.

Comment: Did you try e.g. `{{unsecure_base_url}}media/` for media url?